# How to make dwmapi (Desktop Windows Manager API) work in Windows XP?

Tags: dwm

I'm doing a windows application using dwmapi.dll on C# and it's not working in windows XP because XP didn't support Desktop Windows Manager API (dwmapi.dll). It's only supported in Vista and Win 7. Anyone knows how to make dwmapi (Desktop Windows Manager API) work in Windows XP?

Thanks,
jron

Comment: Not going to happen. XP uses GDI, while Vista and 7 use WDM.

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles on this question and despairs, it is possible to have an application using dwmapi that will run on XP - you just need to disable the dwmapi parts using DelayLoading. There are some good answers on that here and on other sites.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make DWM work in Windows XP.

Like it or not, that is the answer.